# How this constructor call is working?

Tags: java, constructor

Can anyone explain how this constructor call is working. Because I was assuming that it should print

> hello from class A
>
> hello from class B
>
> hello from class C

I am confused here. Any help is appreciated. Below is my code.

```
public class A {
   A(){
    System.out.println("hello from class A");
  }
}

public class B extends A {
  B(){
    System.out.println("hello from class B");
    }
 }

public class C extends B {
 C(B b){    
     System.out.println("hello from class C");
    }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    new C(new B());
    }
 }

  //result

  hello from class A
  hello from class B
  hello from class A
  hello from class B
  hello from class C
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each constructor of a derived class first constructs its base class: So first you create an object of class B, resulting in A() to be called first. Then you create an object of class C, resulting in A() and B() to be called first.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand first: Base class constructor is called before the extended class constructor.

Here we go, Starting from main:

```
new C(new B()); // new B() is created first before being passed to C
```

**Making B object:**

1. calls A class constructor first // prints: hello from class A
2. calls B class constructor after // prints: hello from class B

---

now that the B object is created we can pass it into `new C(new b());` in main

**Making C Object:**

1. calls A class constructor first // prints: hello from class A
2. calls B class constructor second // prints: hello from class B
3. calls C class constructor last // prints: hello from class C

This gives us the following output as expected:

```
hello from class A
hello from class B
hello from class A
hello from class B
hello from class C
```